# Is it possible to tweak Solr hit relevance score based on length of content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I have a Rails app using sunspot to do searches against a table with records of varying sizes. I want to adjust the score of the hit depending on how large a certain field is. This is to punish articles that have very little content but happens to have the term being searched for showing up at the top. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One technique: compute the body length at insertion time and give the whole document a Boost based on its higher length - you'd supply this Boost manually, for each document at index-time.

See this FAQ: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_increase_the_score_for_specific_documents

Comment: Thanks! I think that would work. I will try to remember to report back!

Answer (score 0):

This mailing list thread seems to kind of answer your question - and brings up another point that you might be thinking about this wrong.

http://osdir.com/ml/solr-user.lucene.apache.org/2010-05/msg00916.html

This quote is illustrative: "*I have to ask, though, why you want to sort this way? The relevance calculations already factor in both term frequency and field length. What's
the use-case for sorting by field length given the above?*"

Comment: In my case, there are articles like:

Comment: `title => 'Bingo', content => 'see Silly games.'` When searching for "silly" this article comes up very high on the list. I know there's probably a _right_ answer involving some sort of forwarding article type but for now I was hoping to get solr kinda suppress these articles with very short content. I don't want to sort by the field length as the mailing list thread seems to suggest, I want it to actually factor into the hit score. Maybe it's "wrong" and hacky, but I would still like to know if there's some standard way to affect the score in a custom way.